# trying to print an array in an object, but not working(reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to print the array in this object:

[image]

But, this code is not working:

```
{templates.map(item => { return <li>{item[0]}</li>; })}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using that isn't working?

Comment: {templates.map(item => {
          return <li>{item[0]}</li>;
        })}

Comment: It works best when you edit your question to include your code (I have done it for you).  When creating questions on stackoverflow, please try to remember that we know nothing about your code that you don't tell us.  You are more likely to get downvotes and close votes than answers when your question doesn't include enough information for us to even understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you are using: `item[0]`, it looks like you think `item` is an array, and you are trying to get the value of the first element in the array.  But, looking at the object, you can see that `templates` contains Objects, not Arrays.  So, `item[0]` is undefined.

This begs the question, what do you mean when you say you want to "print the array"?  Do you want to print the JSON string that represents each object?

```
templates.map(item => <li>{JSON.stringify(item)}</li>)
```

Or do you want to print the value of the sole property on the object?

```
templates.map(item => <li>{item.Template_id}</li>)
```

Here's a working example, that prints the `Template_id` property of each item in the `templates` array:

```js
const obj = {
  name: "After_Effects",
  templates: [
    { Template_id: "601071694b0146303c10d68c" },
    { Template_id: "601072e04b0146303c10d68d" },
    { Template_id: "601073114b0146303c10d68e" },
  ],
  __v: 0,
  _id: "60106addf83a155344bf3edb",
};
const listItems = obj.templates.map(item => <li>{item.Template_id}</li>);
ReactDOM.render(<ul>{listItems}</ul>, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```